# Cómo funcionan los módulos que hay clases y otras clase dentro

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulos

Esto va porque porque ejemplo, con "Pygame" la importarlo puedes crear un sprite, pero para ello lo heredas a tu clase, por ejemplo.

```
import pygame

class Jugador(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
```

"pygame" es el módulo, "sprite" es la clase, entonces ¿El "Sprite" es otra clase dentro de otra?

Comment: A veces el nombre te da pistas. Los nombres de clases se suelen escribir con la primera letra en mayúsculas, los nombres de módulos, funciones y variables con la primera letra en minúscula. `pygame.sprite` parece un módulo del paquete pygame, mientras que `Sprite` parece una clase del módulo `sprite`.

Comment: Ahh vale, entiendo, pero al hacer Import pygame, puedo hacer otras funciones como pygame.Clock(), por lo que entendí que al hacer Import pygame es un módulo, no un paquete, así que ahí ando también confuso.

Comment: En realidad, no es tan complicado como lo ves. Todas las cosas en python tiene un nombre que las referencia. El conjunto de todos estos nombres se conoce por _espacio de nombres_ (_namespace_). Cuando haces un import, lo que haces es traer un namespace al tuyo de trabajo. Así `import pygame` lo que hace es accesible el namespace `pygame`, el cuál tendrá nombres (eg: `pygame.Clock`) y también otros namespaces (eg: `pygame.sprite`). La idea es poder referenciar los objetos que necesitas para tu programa.